# Use "-replace" to compare and replace more variations of a string

Tags: powershell, replace

I have to check if a string matches with one of these four strings and then replace the string. How can I do it?

I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
$NewOne = $One -replace("111" -or "112" -or "113" -or "114","000")
```

Instead of those numbers it should write 000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use parentheses with [operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.0).

As `-replace` is RegEx based either use [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)  or a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html)

```
$NewOne = $One -replace '111|112|113|114','000'
```

or

```
$NewOne = $One -replace '11[1-4]','000'
```